# Не перезаписивается кука!

Tags: php, cookie

Cоздаю cookie через setcookie(). Она создается, а когда еще раз пишу setcookie(), то уже не записивается. Значение то же как у первой!

Есть созданая кука

```
setcookie('likes',serialize($arr),time()+3600*24*365,'/','si‌​te.com');
```

перезаписиваю так

```
setcookie('likes',serialize($arr));
```

и не перезаписивает

Comment: Подробней проблему опишите. В текущем состоянии мало что понятно.

Comment: Есть созданая кука setcookie('likes',serialize($arr),time()+3600*24*365,'/','site.com'); перезаписиваю так setcookie('likes',serialize($arr)); и не перезаписивает @Visman

Comment: Во втором случае 3-5 параметры следует также задать аналогично первому случаю.

Comment: @visman не работает